# Is it always true that if $A = \int_a^b f(x) dx$ then $A - c = \int_a^b (f(x) -c) dx$?

Tags: real-analysis

> If $A = \int_a^b f(x) dx$, then $A - c = \int_a^b (f(x) -c) dx$.

Would this always be true for constants or functions that are in a different variable from the variable of integration (example: $c = f(y)$?

Would this need to be proven if it come up in the proof of another result or is it more or less clear?

Comment: What if $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$?

Comment: You are basically saying $A-c=\int_a^b f(x)\,dx - (b-a)c$ or indeed $c=(b-a)c$ or $b-a=1$ (or $c=0$) which might or might not be true

Comment: $\int_a^b (f(x) -c) dx = \int_a^b f(x) dx  - \int_a^b c\ dx$ and if $c$ is constant $\int_a^b c\ dx = (b-a)c$

Answer (score 2):

$\int_a^b c= c(b-a)=c$ if and only if $c=0$ or $b-a=1$.  So this works on an interval of length $1$.  Otherwise, the correct identity would be $A-c=\int_a^b f(x)-\frac{c}{b-a}\,dx$.